# How to programmatically trigger event in among thousand same div using Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I Google a lot but couldn't find the exact solution for it.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let module of modules">
     <a id={{module.id}} (click)=onClickSection(module)></a>
  </div>
```

How can I programmatically called the click event on a particular condition in an Angular 4 Component?
I know this can be done by using

```
@ViewChild('elementId') element;
```

but this is not a solution for me bcz in my case there are thousand of ClickEvent to be but I need only one ClickEvent.

Comment: You shouldn't render thousands of items anyway. I doubt they are all visible at the same time and no user will be able to click invisible elements.

Comment: Actually It's requirement and need to show.

Comment: So you show 10k buttons at once on your screen?
Actually I don't understand what the problem is or what you try to accomplish. You already have an `(click)="onClickSelection(module)"`. So what is not working? What does "case there are thousand of ClickEvent" mean? Who clicks thousands of times. What is she clicking on?

Comment: I want programmatically click the button not. 
E.g If some action occur then particular button will be clicked

Comment: Which button do you want to click? How can the specific button you want to have clicked be differentiated from the others?

Comment: it's dynamic service call not specific

Comment: I think our question doesn't provide a single bit of **concrete** information that would allow to provide an answer while I'm quite sure that it would be quite simple to answer when it's clear what the question is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160491/discussion-between-yasir-shabbir-choudhary-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have time for that. Please try to make it clear what the problem is (what you try to accomplish), what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: Although you are specifying any number of event handlers, there is only one function that you are calling. The parameters to the function varies. If you want to automatically call `onClickSection` with apt param when a condition is met, you can directly call it from within the code of your component and it can have the same effect. Hope this helps.